# Círculo com borda curvada

Tags: html, css, svg, css-border, css-border-radius

fui encarregado de fazer um site, e estou com dificuldade em fazer um detalhe em CSS

Preciso fazer uma borda redonda que tenha um final curvado, para vocês entenderem melhor, vou mostrar foto e postar meu código

Oque eu preciso (Photoshop)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque eu tenho
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de uma solução CSS, mas não consegui

```css
.bottom-bar {
  background: #29a7e8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #29a7e8;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-bar">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Acredito que uma solução em css não exista, e sim usando imagens

Comment: O que você precisa é de um cálculo de curva senoidal em CSS, que felizmente existe, veja este modelo: https://codepen.io/diessica/pen/keLBq

Comment: @RogérioDec na verdade esse exemplo é uma pancada de div rotacionada uma alinhada a outra... Veja que com o filtro SVG vc consegui isso com poucas linhas e aplica direto na div. []´s

Comment: @RogérioDec por sinal, esse Pen que você postou é de uma das pessoas que esteve conosco desde o "começo" do SOpt:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1089/ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usando os *filters* do **SVG** acredito que vc consegue um resultado bem próximo ao da imagem. Eu não vou entrar em detalhes pois o assunto é extenso. Mas deixei comentado no código onde vc controla a intensidade da curvatura entra a bola e a barra. E abaixo deixo algumas explicações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que na tag do SVG tem apenas o filtro e as configurações dos filtros. Depois de definí-las usei o `filter:url(#filter)` para chamar o filtro na barra e nos elementos que estão dentro. Por isso precisei de uma `div` nova por fora (`.base`) para evitar distorções nos cantos da barra que vai receber o filtro.

Para entender melhor veja o exemplo abaixo. Veja também que funciona do IE 10 para frente: https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters

**OBS:** Deixei uma imagem de fundo no background e uma animação no final do CSS apenas para vc ver como é a interação do efeito do filtro entre os elementos. *Sei que não precisa da animação, mas é apenas para fins didáticos, ok.*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.base {
    background: #29a7e8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.bottom-bar {
    background: #29a7e8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    filter: url(#filter);
}
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #29a7e8;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
/* apenas exemplo */
.circle:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation: anima 2s infinite ease;
        animation: anima 2s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anima {
50% {
    top: -100px;
}
}
@keyframes anima {
50% {
    top: -100px;
}
}
body {
background: url(http://unsplash.it/600/400);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
    <div class="bottom-bar">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="filter">
        <!-- aqui vc controla a curvatura entre a bola e a barra, deixei 5 para ficar acentuado e vc perceber, mas com 3 fica como vc quer mais suave -->
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur"/> 
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="filter"/>
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="filter" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

- Filtros SVG https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter
- Como aplicar filtros nos elementos SVG no Elementos HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content

Comment: Obrigado amigo, ajudou demais demais demais, perfeita solução!

Comment: @YungSilva sem problemas meu amigo, sucesso com o projeto, esse artificio dos filtros svg da pra fazer muita coisa criativa!

Comment: Gostei dessa solução. Você pode explicar um pouco mais como funciona esse "blending" das formas no SVG?

Comment: @bfavaretto então, se vc for retirando os filtros aos poucos vc vai entender um pouco melhor. Primeiro vc coloca o blur para fazer os "esfumaçado" nas bordas do elementos, depois com a matriz rgba vetor (1 0 0 0 0) vc ajusta a mascara de um blur entrando no outro, e com o composite vc coloca os dois filtros juntos. Tem muito material sobre isso com explicações bem técnicas, procure por Gooey Effect, no MDN tem material tecnico sobre todos os filtros SVG tb. Aqui tem um excelente artigo http://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix com o diagrama explicado perfeitamente a matriz

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar dois pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after` com curva (`border-radius`) na borda inferior (`bottom`) e posiciona-los nos respectivos cantos.

Veja como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```css
.bottom-bar {
  background: #29a7e8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #29a7e8;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.circle::before,
.circle::after{
   content: '';
   background: #fff; /* mesma cor do fundo da página */
   padding: 1px 1px 0;
   width: 6px;
   height: 2px;
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #29a7e8; /* borda inferior na cor azul */
   z-index: -1;
   top: 7px;
}

.circle::before{
   left: 2px;
   border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}

.circle::after{
   right: 2px;
   border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-bar">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```