# Alguém me ajuda com esse efeito?

Tags: html, css

Alguém sabe fazer esse efeito de "curva" na div?
link da [img](https://dribbble.com/shots/6668411-The-Tab-Bar-Interaction?utm_source=Pinterest_Shot&utm_campaign=ngocdangtb&utm_content=The%20Tab%20Bar%20Interaction&utm_medium=Social_Share)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tava tentando fazer mais não consegui. O código que tava usando:

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    background:#7ABCFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    
}
.menuCont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
.menu{
    background: #fff;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0px; 
}
.icons{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menuCurva{
    background: #fff;
}
.menuCurva:before{
    content:'';
    padding: 5px; /* um espaçamento de 5px é suficiente */
    background: #fff; /* mesmo fundo da página */
    width:2px;
    height: 50%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0; /* curvo a borda de baixo */ /* borda inferior em 5px na cor preta */
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
}

.menuCurva:after {
    content:'';
    padding: 5px; /* um espaçamento de 5px é suficiente */
    background: #fff; /* mesmo fundo da página */
    width:2px;
    height: 40%;
    float:left;
    border-radius: 0 100% 0 0; /* curvo a borda da direita */
    right: 1px; 
    position: relative;
    bottom: 19px;
}

.teste{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    background: #7ABCFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menuCont">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="icons">

            </div>
            <div class="icons">

            </div>
            <div class="icons menuCurva">
                <div class="teste">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">

            </div>
            <div class="icons">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não poste a pergunta de novo se ela já foi fechada, leia o motivo do fechamento e melhore a pergunta antiga

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299864/c%c3%adrculo-com-borda-curvada

Comment: muito obrigado, vou da uma olhada, acho que vai me ajudar bastante

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segue um exemplo usando pseudo elementos com a mesma cor da barra, e um círculo no centro com a cor da borda igual a cor do fundo.

Primeiro veja com cores diferente para vc identificar os elementos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora com as cores certas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sego o código a imagem acima, repare principalmente nos alinhamento dos pseudo elementos e do círculo

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: tomato;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: navy;
}
.bar::before,
.bar::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
  background-color: navy;
}
.bar::before {
  left: 0;
}
.bar::after {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  right: 0;
}
.boll {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 10px solid tomato;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="boll"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma bem simples de fazer esse efeito, usando pseudos-elementos e `border-radius`. Alterei a posição do `.menuCurva` para se ajustar dentro da div `.icons` onde ele está.

> **Erro:** o width do body está errado. Deveria ser `100wh` e não `100vh`.

**Uma observação:** esse menu deveria ser feito com dimensões fixas, já que, pela sua estrutura, não me parece ter a pretensão de ser responsivo.

No exemplo abaixo fiz ele com dimensões fixas de 300x60. É importante que as divs `.icons` sejam quadradas, ou seja, de a altura possuir `60px` e são 5 ícones, logo a largura deverá ter `300px` (resultado de 5 * 60px).

**Veja o exemplo:**

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100wh;
    background:#7ABCFF;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.menu, .icons, .menuCurva{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.menuCont{
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px; /* remova isto */
}

.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 20px 20px; 
    position: relative;
}
.icons{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icons:nth-child(1){
   border-radius: 40% 0 0 25%;
}

.icons:nth-child(1)::before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: -4px;
   background: #fff;
   height: 100%;
   width: 4px;
}

.icons:nth-child(2){
   border-top-right-radius: 50%;
   left: 4px;
   padding-right: 4px;
}

.icons:nth-child(3)::after{
   content: '';
   width: calc(100% + 10px);
   height: 100%;
   background: #7ABCFF;
   border-radius: 50%;
   bottom: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}

.icons:nth-child(4){
   border-top-left-radius: 50%;
   left: -4px;
   padding-left: 4px;
}


.icons:nth-child(5){
   border-radius: 0 40% 25% 0;
}

.icons:nth-child(5)::before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -4px;
   background: #fff;
   height: 100%;
   width: 4px;
}

.menuCurva{
   background: navy;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 65%;
   left: 50%;
   -webikit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuCont">
  <div class="menu">
      <div class="icons">
         +
      </div>
      <div class="icons">
         +
      </div>
      <div class="icons">
          <div class="menuCurva">
            +
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="icons">
         +
      </div>
      <div class="icons">
         +
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou muito bom tb tio!